# Why do my doubles display as integers when I pass them to cout?

Tags: c++

I have set of coordinates stored in a file. I extracted only the “x” coordinate of certain points and stored in a vector called:

```
vector<double> x_points;
```

Then, I need to get the values of minimum and maximum x coordinates inside that vector. So I used `*max_element` and `*min_element` by including `<algorithm>`;

```
double max_in=*max_element(x_points.begin(),x_points.end());
double min_in=*min_element(x_points.begin(),x_points.end());
```

then, when I print the values, using

```
cout<<" min-max-In "<<min_in<<" "<<max_in<<" ";
```

...it shows only the integer part. I need the whole value with decimal parts. So, how can I get the real value, because I need those to do another process with those values?
Thank you. Any help please.

Comment: show us how you print the values?

Comment: The problem is in the printing out, or the insertion into the vector: the two crucial steps of your program that you neglected to show us.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in saving or loading data

Comment: @ tony; i simple use, cout<<" min-max-In "<<min_in<<" "<<max_in<<" ";

Comment: when, i try to cout z values i got the whole but, not x values. for e.g. z 343.83
343.73
343.13, but X values like 512266
512265
512265. here the decimal part is missing.

Comment: I think you need to add more code. What are Z values?? If I try what you are doing, with doubles, I get what I expect. So there must be a problem with how you fill x_points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You print the values with the default precision, which is 6 digits. Exactly what you get!

Try adding a `cout.precision(10);` to get more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you dont use `std::set` rather than vector? Then they would naturally be ordered. That said it would destroy the original order and any duplicates (unless you use `std::multiset`) if that's important to you.

Alternatively, you could work out the max / min as you read in as in the following example. I did a bit of breif profiling on it and really didn't add any appreciable processing time.

```
vector<double> xcoords;
double d, dMax, dMin;
bool firstLine(true);

ifstream inFile( argv[1] );
while ( inFile.good() )
{
    inFile >> d;
    if ( ! inFile.good() || inFile.eof() ) break;
    xcoords.push_back(d);

    if (firstLine)
    {
        dMax = d;
        dMin = d;
        firstLine = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dMax = max( dMax, d );
        dMin = min( dMin, d );
    }
}

cout << dMax << " " << dMin << " " << xcoords.size()  << endl;
```

Comment: thank you very much for showing me other possibilities. so far, i didnt use set. thanks....